# Access previous records from a table variable without using cursor in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, stored-procedures, optimization, query-performance

In a stored procedure, I have to do some calculation based on the previous record and a total. Currently I can achieve this using Cursor or a table variable, but its taking a lot of time as the number of records are huge.
How can I achieve this to improve the performance?

A part of my stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @HoursTemp TABLE
    (
        ID [INT],
        EmployeeName [VARCHAR](100),
        WorkDate [DATE],
        RegularHours [DECIMAL],
        OvertimeHours [DECIMAL],
        NightJob [BIT],
        JobId [INT]
    )

    INSERT INTO @HoursTemp
    SELECT ID, EmployeeName, WorkDate, RegularHours,OvertimeHours, NightJob, JobId
            FROM @PayrollSheet              
            GROUP BY WorkDate, EmployeeName , JobIdType,  NightJob, RegularHours, OvertimeHours, ID, JobId
            ORDER BY WorkDate, EmployeeName, JobIdType, NightJob, JobId

     SELECT @count = COUNT(ID) FROM @HoursTemp WHILE (@i <= @count)
     BEGIN
        Print @i
        SELECT @PayRollID = ID ,
        @EmployeeName = EmployeeName,
        @WorkDate = WorkDate,
        @RegularHours = RegularHours,
        @OverTimeHour = OvertimeHours,
        @NightHours = NightJob,
        @PayRollJobID = JobId
        FROM @HoursTemp     

        IF(@WorkDate = @PreviousDate AND @EmployeeName = @PreviousEmployeeName) -- If Current date and previous date matches
        BEGIN

            SET @SumOfHours = @SumOfHours + @RegularHours;  -- Then Sum up the regular hour with previous hour.
            IF(@SumOfHours >= 8 AND @SumOverTimeHours = 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @SumOverTimeHours = @OverTimeHour + (@SumOfHours - 8); -- Sum up the overtime hour.
                    SET @RegularHours = 8 - (@SumOfHours - @RegularHours);  -- Get remainder regular hour.

                    UPDATE @PayrollSheet SET RegularHours = @RegularHours, OvertimeHours = @SumOverTimeHours Where ID = @PayRollID  -- Update the temp table.
                END     
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --When sum of regular hours is greater than 8, further regular hours of the day will be considered as over time hours.
                    IF(@SumOfHours >=8)
                        UPDATE @PayrollSheet SET RegularHours = 0, OvertimeHours = @RegularHours Where ID = @PayRollID  --Update the over time hours with regular hour and set regular hour with 0.
                END     
        END 
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @SumOfHours = @RegularHours; -- If Dates does not match then reset the regular hours sum variable to current regular hours so it will be summed with next regular hours when dates match.
                SET @SumOverTimeHours = 0;  -- Sum up Over time hours present in existing records.
                --SET @SumOfNightHours = 0; -- Reset OverTime Sum and Night hours sum variable when dates does not match.
            END 

        -- Get counts of record with same work date,Job ID and Night Job true and match it with total records with same work date.          
        SELECT @RecordsWithWorkDateAndJobID = COUNT(*) from @PayrollSheet where WorkDate = @WorkDate AND JobID = @PayRollJobID AND NightJob = 1 AND EmployeeName = @EmployeeName
        SELECT @RecordsWithOnlyWorkDate = COUNT(*) from @PayrollSheet where WorkDate = @WorkDate AND EmployeeName = @EmployeeName --AND NightJob = 1

        --If both count matches then night hours are entered in same job on a day. Else night hours are entered in more than one job. Also if sum of night hours is less than 8 then only update night hours.
        IF(NOT(@RecordsWithWorkDateAndJobID > 0 AND @RecordsWithOnlyWorkDate > 0 AND @RecordsWithWorkDateAndJobID = @RecordsWithOnlyWorkDate)) --AND @SumOfNightHours < 8 
            BEGIN                       
                UPDATE @PayrollSheet SET NightJob = 0 Where ID = @PayRollID -- Set regular hours as 0 and night hours as the regular hour.
                --SET @SumOfNightHours = @SumOfNightHours + @RegularHours; -- Maintain sum of night hours, so that if it is greater than 8 then night hours will not be added.
            END

        SET @PreviousDate = @WorkDate   --Store previous work date.     
        SET @PreviousJobID = @PayRollJobID -- Store previous job id.
        SET @PreviousEmployeeName = @EmployeeName

        -- Fetch next record from temp table.    

        SELECT @i = @i + 1
     END
```

Comment: Since you are on Sql 2014, have you looked into using the LEAD and LAG windowing functions that were introduce in 2012? - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/lead-and-lag-functions-in-sql-server-2012.html - I'd also recommend refraining from using table variables if you are dealing with a large number of rows - the optimizer can often generate poor execution plans when using table variables

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why your code can not be simplified to something like this?:

```
insert into @HoursTemp (
    Id, EmployeeName, WorkDate
  , RegularHours, OvertimeHours, NightJob, JobId
  )
select 
    Id
  , EmployeeName
  , WorkDate
  , RegularHours  = case 
      when sum(RegularHours) > 8 
        then 8 
      else sum(RegularHours) 
      end
  , OvertimeHours = case 
      when sum(RegularHours) > 8 
        then sum(RegularHours) - 8 
      else 0 
      end
  , NightJob
  , JobId
from @PayrollSheet
group by 
    Id
  , EmployeeName
  , WorkDate
  , NightJob  
  --, JobIdType  /* Why are grouping by this but not inserting this into @HoursTemp */
  , JobId 
order by WorkDate, EmployeeName, NightJob, JobId
```

All of your code related to `@SumOfNightHours` is commented out, is that because it does not work yet or because the requirements changed?